# How to direct users to their own designed menus

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have created a 3 level user access database in MS Access 2007 and what I would like to happen is when each user logs in they are directed straight to their own purpose build menus i.e. Admin Menu, Developer Menu and User Menu.

At the moment whichever user logs in gets directed straight to the main menu and if the user logged in only has the access level of a user he can still access admin and developer tables/forms etc.

Below is the VB code I have inputted for when the user enters their password and logs in.  What additional code can I put in so it directs each specific user to their menu?

```
Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()

'Check that EE is selected
If IsNull(Me.cboUser) Then
    MsgBox "You need to select a user!", vbCritical
    Me.cboUser.SetFocus
Else
    'Check for correct password
    If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) Then
        'Check if password needs to be reset
        If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPasswordChange", , , "[UserID] = " & Me.cboUser
        End If
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainMenu"
        Me.Visible = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
        Me.txtPassword = Null
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us how you associate group membership information with user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column to `cboUser` that says the `UserType`.  Then instead of having this:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainMenu"
```

You would have something like this:

```vb
Select Case Me.cboUser.Column(4) 'Assuming 4 is the UserType column
    Case "Admin"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdmin"
    Case "Developer"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDeveloper"
    Case "User"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUser"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "An error has occurred"
End Select
```

Just adjust for proper naming.  This just has the system open to the form meant for that type of user.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm trying what you've suggested above and it's not seeming to work the pop up box appears "An error has occurred". Now i created an extra column in the table tblUsers and called it UserType and then on the login form i've inputted the above VB Code adjusted the names so they match the names i have used.

Comment: all that pops up is "An error has occurred" and then just closes the login page down. What I've also done is added the UserType column to my query i have set for cboUser, cboUser is the name for the combo box on the login form for username where the user selects from a drop down their name and it still won't pick it up

Comment: Do you have error handling or anything that would stop it from letting you debug or view the full error?

Comment: I've got it to work now thanks for your help. Only issue is that the login page doesn't close down once the user has logged in am i missing something from the code.

Comment: Select Case Me.cboUser.Column(4) 
    Case "1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdminMenu"
    Case "2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdminMenu"
    Case "3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserMenu"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "An error has occurred"
         Me.Visible = False
       End Select

Comment: got a separate question is there anyway in access 2007 to hide the navigation pane just from a user only. I know you can hide the ribbons but that hides it from everyone. I would like the navigation pane hidden when the user logs in and have it visible when either the admin or developer logs in